# auto.arima produces non-gaussian residual

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm using R's `auto.arima`function - but it seems like that it does not produce gaussian errors all the time. I cannot find any documentation that it does some bootstrapping of the prediction error (if the error is not gaussian), or what it does if the error is not gaussian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimation does not require Gaussian errors, even when a Gaussian likelihood is being used. A Gaussian likelihood is almost the same as least squares and will give consistent estimates for any error distribution with finite variance.

The only time that the distribution of residuals really matters is when producing prediction intervals. If the residuals are not Gaussian, the default prediction intervals will not necessarily have the correct coverage. But then you can set `bootstrap=TRUE` and get bootstrapped prediction intervals which are based on the empirical distribution of the residuals.